# Get series from idxmax

Tags: pandas

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A   B   C
0  123  3   2
1   2   8   1
2   4   11  3

3 rows x 3 columns
```

And I have it's respective `idxmax()` Series as

```
A  0
B  2
3  2
Lenght: 3, dtype: int64
```

Now, I have a second dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0  'a'  7  'c'
1  'b'  5  'a'
2  'c'  2  'd'
```

So, using the `idxmax()` series computed previously, I want to retrieve the respective values within each column, and get the series

```
A 'a'
B  5
C 'd'
Lenght: 3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with `Series` conctructor:

```
s = df1.idxmax()

a = pd.Series(df2.lookup(s, s.index), index=s.index)
print (a)
A    'a'
B    '2'
C    'd'
dtype: object
```

Comment: Rock on! Thanks a lot.